# Laravel - Query builder with pivot table, return where all in

Tags: laravel-5

I have tables customers, products and `customer_products`. 
In `customer_products` there are `id`, `customer_id` and `product_id` columns.
In search form I have '`products`' input field, and can add multiple products for searching. 
So, in that case `$request->products` is array, and I want to pass that array in query builder to return all customers who bought at least all products from `$request->products` array.
If each customers had only one products I would then use whereIn method, but when customers has multiple products ordered I dont have idea how to solve that. 
I tried with foreach but I did not get the result which want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution. If someone has same problem this is solution which gives me correct results, whereHas method is what I need for:

```
$customesrs = Customers::with('products');
if($request->has('products'))
{
  foreach($request->products as $product)
  {
   $customers->whereHas('products', function($query) use ($product) {
     $query->where('product_id', $product);
   });
  }
}
$customers->get();
```